# How to create conditional instance attribute in python which can only take value >= 5000,else prompt user that minimum is 5000?

Tags: python, class, attributes, instance

I have class 'Player' in python and wanna create instance attribute 'deposit',which intended take integer equal or greather 5000,else raise error or to ask user set valid value.So I tried implement that with 'if else' but it is not the satisfying result.

class Player:

```
def __init__(self, deposit):
    if deposit >= 5000:
        self.deposit = deposit
    else:
        print('Minimum deposit is 5000')
```

pl = Player(4000)
pl.deposit // AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'deposit'

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to set the value after the message with the minimum deposit was displayed, or just display the error and after that the user needs to create the instance with a value >= 5000?

Comment: @Ake ideally programm need to alert that 'your deposit is invalid,set deposit >= 5000'

Comment: If you want the user to be able to correct the value, why do you need that constraint as part of the class definition? It seems more intuitive that the whole action of instantiation should be re-evaluated, so you could put whatever code is creating that instance in a `while` that evaluates the input or the attribute itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an AttributeError because the `deposit` attribute is not created when the deposit value is less than 5000.
If you want to prompt the user to set a valid deposit value when the deposit is less than 5000, you can use a loop and the input() function to prompt the user until a valid deposit value is entered like this:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, deposit):
        while deposit < 5000:
            print('Minimum deposit is 5000')
            deposit = int(input('Enter a valid deposit value: '))
        self.deposit = deposit

pl = Player(4000)
pl.deposit
```

And if you want to just raise the error you can do it like this:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, deposit):
        if deposit >= 5000:
            self.deposit = deposit
        else:
            raise ValueError('Minimum deposit is 5000')

pl = Player(4000)
pl.deposit
```

Comment: tnx Ake,that's what I need,I'm beginner and this is for my pet-project so btw is there more optimal method?I mean this one is quiet optimal and redable even for beginner :),but is there topic I shold learn about tasks like this?

Comment: I would suggest focusing on the fundamentals of object-oriented programming (OOP) in Python. Understanding classes, objects, inheritance, and polymorphism is going to help you if you want to do things like this.

Comment: really tnx for help